# java ajax method getting confused when called by multiple sources

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have some a java portlet application which calls a restful service. I have struck a problem where it looks like I am coming across a threadsafe issue. I have a servlet specifically used for Ajax calls. This servlet is called from myultiple locations at the same time.

It looks like my application is getting confused because the Ajax servlet is receiving multiple requests from different locations at the same time. I didn't think that this would be a problem.

Can someone help me understand the issue and secondly suggest a way to fix/improve? I think I will struggle to put a code snippet here because it will be too large to demonstrate the issue.

But basically the pattern is that I fire some 2 ajax requests from javascript to a servlet at the same time with different parameters. The handling of the servlet request is different based ont he different parameters passed in. But they both call the same java static methods to handle creating json objects. And it's those static methods that look like they are getting confused.

When I'm printing debug messages in the static methods the static methods show the debug info from the first call and then the static methods start showing debug info from the second call before the first is finished.

thanks for the help and sorry for no code snippet (probably too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to check if there are methods that using same non-threadsafe resources (i.e. HashMap in the field, or something). If there are, add locks or get rid of these fields (make them local).